# Unable to show popup menu in Adapter in Android

Tags: android, menu, popupmenu

I am developing an Android app. In my app, I am showing pop up menu in Recycler view adapter. But it is giving me error.

In onBindViewHolder of RecyclerViewAdapter, I am showing pop up menu like this

```
viewHolder.container.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onLongClick(View view) {
                PopupMenu popupMenu = new PopupMenu(context,view);
                popupMenu.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
                        return false;
                    }
                });
                popupMenu.inflate(R.menu.menu_mm_comment_item);

                popupMenu.show();
                return true;
            }
```

But when I fire long click event, it is giving me this error.

> FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                                                         Process: com.tonightfootball.waiyanhein.tonightfootballreport, PID:
>   28052
>                                                                                                         android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #17: Failed to
>   resolve attribute at index 6: TypedValue{t=0x1d/d=0xff5c5cff a=1
>   r=0x106002f}
>                                                                                                             at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:539)
>                                                                                                             at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
>                                                                                                             at
>   android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuAdapter.getView(MenuAdapter.java:93)
>                                                                                                             at
>   android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuPopup.measureIndividualMenuWidth(MenuPopup.java:160)
>                                                                                                             at
>   android.support.v7.view.menu.StandardMenuPopup.tryShow(StandardMenuPopup.java:153)
>                                                                                                             at
>   android.support.v7.view.menu.StandardMenuPopup.show(StandardMenuPopup.java:187)
>                                                                                                             at
>   android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuPopupHelper.showPopup(MenuPopupHelper.java:290)
>                                                                                                             at
>   android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuPopupHelper.tryShow(MenuPopupHelper.java:175)
>                                                                                                             at
>   android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuPopupHelper.show(MenuPopupHelper.java:141)
>                                                                                                             at android.support.v7.widget.PopupMenu.show(PopupMenu.java:233)
>                                                                                                             at
>   com.tonightfootball.waiyanhein.adapter.MemeCommentsAdapter$1.onLongClick(MemeCommentsAdapter.java:113)
>                                                                                                             at android.view.View.performLongClick(View.java:5237)
>                                                                                                             at android.view.View$CheckForLongPress.run(View.java:21121)
>                                                                                                             at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
>                                                                                                             at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>                                                                                                             at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
>                                                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
>                                                                                                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                                                             at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
>                                                                                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
>                                                                                                          Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Failed to resolve
>   attribute at index 6: TypedValue{t=0x1d/d=0xff5c5cff a=1 r=0x106002f}
>                                                                                                             at
>   android.content.res.TypedArray.getLayoutDimension(TypedArray.java:705)
>                                                                                                             at
>   android.view.ViewGroup$LayoutParams.setBaseAttributes(ViewGroup.java:6890)
>                                                                                                             at
>   android.view.ViewGroup$MarginLayoutParams.(ViewGroup.java:7071)
>                                                                                                             at
>   android.widget.FrameLayout$LayoutParams.(FrameLayout.java:446)
>                                                                                                             at
>   android.widget.FrameLayout.generateLayoutParams(FrameLayout.java:386)
>                                                                                                             at
>   android.widget.FrameLayout.generateLayoutParams(FrameLayout.java:385)
>                                                                                                             at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:502)
>                                                                                                             at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423) 
>                                                                                                             at
>   android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuAdapter.getView(MenuAdapter.java:93) 
>                                                                                                             at
>   android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuPopup.measureIndividualMenuWidth(MenuPopup.java:160) 
>                                                                                                             at
>   android.support.v7.view.menu.StandardMenuPopup.tryShow(StandardMenuPopup.java:153) 
>                                                                                                             at
>   android.support.v7.view.menu.StandardMenuPopup.show(StandardMenuPopup.java:187) 
>                                                                                                             at
>   android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuPopupHelper.showPopup(MenuPopupHelper.java:290) 
>                                                                                                             at
>   android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuPopupHelper.tryShow(MenuPopupHelper.java:175) 
>                                                                                                             at
>   android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuPopupHelper.show(MenuPopupHelper.java:141) 
>                                                                                                             at android.support.v7.widget.PopupMenu.show(PopupMenu.java:233) 
>                                                                                                             at
>   com.tonightfootball.waiyanhein.adapter.MemeCommentsAdapter$1.onLongClick(MemeCommentsAdapter.java:113) 
>                                                                                                             at android.view.View.performLongClick(View.java:5237) 
>                                                                                                             at android.view.View$CheckForLongPress.run(View.java:21121) 
>                                                                                                             at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739) 
>                                                                                                             at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
>                                                                                                             at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
>                                                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
>                                                                                                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>                                                                                                             at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
>                                                                                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)

I tried this way as well.

```
viewHolder.container.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onLongClick(View view) {
                PopupMenu popupMenu = new PopupMenu(context,view);
                popupMenu.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                        public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
                        return false;
                   }
                });
                popupMenu.getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_mm_comment_item,popupMenu.getMenu());

                popupMenu.show();
                return true;
            }
        });
```

I just got the same error. This is my menu xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <item android:id="@+id/m_item_edit_com" android:title="Edit" app:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText" />
    <item android:id="@+id/m_item_delete_com" android:title="Delete" app:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText" />
</menu>
```

What is wrong with my code?

Comment: What is set to minSdkVersion in your manifest/build.gradle, and what is API level on device you are using?

Comment: MinSdkVersion is 16 and i am testing on Nexus 5 with version 6.0.

Answer (score 2):

Finally found the solution to this problem, though I have no explanation why this solution works.

With the following import I always had the error:

```
import android.support.v7.widget.PopupMenu;
```

It works fine with the following import:

```
import android.widget.PopupMenu;
```